# "Крыса была примечательная" or "примечательна"?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные

> У неё была одна странность: она дружила с крысой. Крыса была **примечательная**, жила неизвестно где и приходила на зов.

Почему здесь нет краткой формы прилагательного, т.е. **примечательна**? Это ведь (пожалуй составное) сказуемое.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сказуемое - "была примечательная". Это составное именное сказуемое. Именная часть сказуемого в принципе может выражаться разными частями речи - и существительным, и кратким прилагательным, и полным прилагательным (как в данном случае).

"Крыса была примечательна - жила неизвестно где..." - это значит, что крыса была примечательна именно тем, что жила неизвестно где.

"Крыса была примечательная, жила неизвестно где..." - это два более-менее независимых утверждения (в том смысле, что крыса, вероятно, была примечательна не только тем, что она жила неизвестно где).

**UPD.** Поскольку полные прилагательные получились из кратких добавлением указательного местоимения, то есть фактически *примечательная* = *примечательна + я* = *примечательна + та самая*, то можно предложить простую аналогию из английского языка:

> Крыса была примечательна --> The rat was remarkable
>   Крыса была примечательна**я** --> The rat was **a** remarkable **one**

Comment: "Примечательная" в данном случае схоже по смыслу с "выдающаяся", "особенная", то есть не такая, как другие.

Comment: Is "Крыса была примечательной" equivalent to "Крыса была примечательна"? Or is it still another nuance?

Comment: @Raskolnikov "Крыса была примечательн**ой** [крысой]" is _быть_ + Instrumental case. About the (other minor) difference between "быть+Nominative" vs "быть+Instrumental" you may want to look at [this question](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BC).