# Краткая и полная форма прилагательного в сказуемом

Tags: грамматика

У меня в голове хаос, и я уже не знаю, что и как.

Меня в школе учили, что в составном сказуемом всегда используется краткая форма прилагательного, и я всегда использовал краткую форму. В другом месте я прочитал, что краткая форма означает временное свойство чего-то, но это так и осталось для меня неясным.

А недавно мне [здесь](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/9126/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/9127#9127) ответили, что могут быть ещё и другие отличия, не совпадающие с тем, о чём я выше писал. Примеры я понимаю, а общий принцип - нет.

Теперь для меня всё это кажется совсем непонятным.

Так что по существу? Когда я должен использовать краткую форму, а когда полную?

Примеры.

Краткая форма:

> Крыса была примечательна. Она была для меня хороша. Решение было очень просто.

Полная:

> Крыса была примечательная/примечательной. Она была для меня хорошая/хорошей. Решение было очень простое/простым.

Comment: Можно пример обоих вариантов?

Comment: @user4419802: Почему вы заменили "сейчас" через "теперь"? Я когда-то читал, что между ними нет разницы. Подходило ли это стилистически лучше?

Comment: @marmistrz Дело в том, что "сейчас" - это исключительно наречие времени (adverb), а "теперь" может быть как наречием, так и союзом (conjunction), аналогично английскому "now". Я посчитал, что в данном случае это немного более уместно по смыслу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нет разницы, то в качестве именной части сказуемого следует использовать краткую форму прилагательного (кстати, её иногда называют также предикативной).

Но дело в том, что зачастую краткие и полные формы прилагательных существенно отличаются друг от друга. Самый очевидный пример - это временные и постоянные признаки. Например, "Он был зол" - he was angry; "Он был злым" - he was evil.

Немного подробнее можно почитать, например, [здесь](http://www.goldrussian.ru/polnye-i-kratkie-prilagatelnye.html).

Что касается приведённых примеров, то тут допустимы обе формы. Происходит это очевидно потому, что они несколько отличаются по смыслу.

"Она хороша" = She's great (either she's pretty or she's a professional); "Она хорошая" = She's a good person.

"Решение было просто" для русского уха это звучит практически как "Принять решение/решить было просто" (Easy to decide/solve), т.е. наречие, а не прилагательное. Вероятно поэтому можно встретить обе формы: "решение было просто" и "решение было простым" (The decision/solution was simple).

UPD. Даже если между краткой и полной формой нет смысловой разницы, то, по крайней мере, стилистическое различие присутствует обязательно: краткая форма звучит резче, чётче, определённее; а полное прилагательное как будто бы намекает на присутствие ещё одного (определяемого) существительного, что даёт какую-то недосказанность, привлекает внимание слушателя. Не удивительно, что в курсах русского языка для иностранцев эту особенность могут опускать, но в художественной литературе такой приём встречается весьма часто.

Теперь к примерам. "*Я был верен этой книге*" и "*Я был верным этой книге*". В принципе, допустимо и одно, и другое, но "*Я был верен*" звучит намного лучше: более чётко, более однозначно, с акцентом на действие - "Я верил этой книге", "Я следовал этой книге" и т.п. "*Я был верным этой книге*" звучит как-то более "размазанно", вяло - ближе к "Я был верным последователем этой книги", "Я был по натуре верным человеком и следовал этой книге" и пр.

"*И я успел обнаружить, что станция эта огромная*." Если заглянуть в оригинал, то окажется, что, на самом деле, предложение на этом не заканчивается: "*И я успел обнаружить, что станция эта огромная, с рационально использованными тупиками и помещениями, с аккуратными надписями и названиями, написанными под трафарет тем самым шрифтом, который бывает только у военных*". То есть здесь идёт подряд несколько определений к слову "станция", разделённых запятыми. В этом случае разумнее использовать полное прилагательное. Но обратите внимание, что при другой *пунктуации* уместнее была бы краткая форма: "И я успел обнаружить, что станция эта огромна: с аккуратными надписями и названиями..." При чтении первый вариант должен звучать плавно (одна большая мысль - "станция и огромная, и с надписями и т.д."), а второй - с заметной паузой в середине предложения (две мысли - "станция была огромна" и "как именно огромна была станция").

"*Разгадка была проста - станцией управляли не просто военные, а военные медики*". Здесь сразу после прилагательного мы видим знак "тире", который недвусмысленно отделяет утверждение ("Разгадка была проста") от последующего пояснения ("Станцией управляли не просто военные..."). Здесь лучшим выбором будет краткая форма "проста", которая удачнее разделяет мысли.

В общем-то тут нет какого-то чёткого правила, но сама тенденция, я надеюсь, понятна.

Comment: А можно ли сказать, видя лишь слово, или у него краткая и полная форма совпадают по значению? Была ли бы разница в таком предложении: *Я был верен этой книге, как присяге несуществующему государству.* Впрочем, ведёт ли себя глагол *оказаться* точно как *быть* насколько дело в форме прилагательного?

Comment: А в таких предложениях (нашёл ещё примеры): *И я успел обнаружить, что станция эта огромная*.Или *Разгадка была проста - станцией управляли не просто военные, а военные медики.* Есть ли здесь тоже разница?

Comment: @marmistrz Я обновил свой ответ.

Comment: @marmistrz Краткие прилагательные сочетаются не со всеми глаголами. В частности, невозможно использовать краткую форму, если глагол требует косвенный падеж: "Он выглядел весёлым". В остальном, вроде бы разницы нет.

Comment: Я бы сказал: краткая форма обычно предпочитается, когда она в неё совмещается целая мысль, а полная - когда она является только частью больше мысли. Правильно ли так сказать?

Comment: @marmistrz Здесь проблема даже больше в стилистической сочетаемости. Краткие прилагательные обычно плохо сочетаются с чем-либо ещё кроме таких же кратких прилагательных. Поэтому "разрыв" в мыслях получается во многом вынужденным. Так что ещё вопрос, что тут является причиной, а что следствием.

Comment: И в таком предложении: *Я уже видел инструкцию, как польоваться (название сайта), но этот сайт сейчас (недоступен/недоступный)*, было бы скорее *недоступный*, правда ли?

Comment: @marmistrz Здесь будет краткая форма: "сайт сейчас недоступен". Это временный признак.

Answer (score 1):

Надёжнее использовать полную форму. Потому что краткая чаще всего звучит абсурдно:

```
У нашего генподрядчика газон зелен.
Наш чизкейк всегда сочен.
Ваш коворкинг безлюден.
```

Вместе с неологизмами из 21 века, краткие прилагательные здесь звучат как пережиток эпохи Пушкина (как из сказки "Конёк-горбунок"). Потому что в 19 веке в литературе было гораздо больше кратких прилагательных, т.к. она больше, чем сегодня, ориентировалась на стандарты церковнославянского.

Краткая форма прилагательного пришла из церковнославянского (древнеболгарского) и поэтому в русском используется в основном на письме и довольно узко. В устную речь они проникли мало, либо в виде устойчивых слов, либо терминов из литературного мира:

```
буду краток
этот тренд устойчив
мой твиттер популярен
этот блоггер известен
```

(все эти прилагательные широко использовались в окололитературной тематике или в технической литературе)

Или краткая форма несёт другой смысл: хорóшая-хорошá.

Остальные прилагательные в краткой форме звучат старомодно и привносят в стиль абсурд.

В русском полная форма сложилась собственно из исконной славянской старой формы и формы личного местоимения (бѣлъ + ый => белый (гласные выпали в другие гласные или исчезли вообще)). В южнославянских краткая форма как была, так и осталась (белый самолёт - "бели авион", и -и на конце - это не "ий", а "ъ", выпавшая в "и").

В общем, это по сути две части речи (хотя родственные, идущие от одного предка).

В русском языке укоренились некоторые вещи из церковнославянского (письменного), но во многих отношениях побеждает устная речь (точнее, письменная всё больше копирует грамматику из устной, которая нам роднее и устойчивее), поэтому надёжнее придерживаться устной (кроме редких случаев, где краткие формы прижились, которые я упомянул выше).

Что касается полной формы прилагательного, есть небольшое различие в употреблении про людей:

```
он был жизнерадостный/жизнерадостным
```

Если нет уточнений на время или длительность, то "-ый" значит "в тот момент" (как в описании: "заходит он жизнерадостный такой"), а "-ым" - что он был таким всегда, и что человека уже нет или он поменялся кардинально.