# Adjectives after "to be"

Tags: прилагательные

How should adjectives be formed after the verb *быть*?

> Он был богат/богатый/богатым.
>
> Фильм будет интересен/интересный/интересным.
>
> Он богат/богатый.

Comment: Related question: [Краткая и полная форма прилагательного в сказуемом](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Comment: I've closed this question because there's another one which mostly overlaps this one. Basically all forms you're asking about are valid in one or another context, but it would be too long a post to cover all of them. If you have a more specific question, please feel free to post it separately, with a little bit of research (what did you try, why do you feel you don't like the result etc.). Thanks!