# Быть с именительным падежом

Tags: падежи, essive, изобразительный-падеж

> Я всё больше держался Кролика. **Кролик был вор** с мистическим уклоном. Жулик и вор он был, впрочем, вполне нормальный. А вот его дружок по грибной тематике был человек особенный.

Почему здесь автор не написал *Кролик был вором*, и вместо этого использовался именительный падеж?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В подтверждение версии, высказанной @user4419802:

> В позиции именной части сказуемого именительный падеж конкурирует с творительным падежом. Форма **именительного** падежа употребляется тогда, когда речь идет о *постоянном* признаке, присущем носителю на протяжении длительного промежутка времени.

[Именительный падеж в позиции именной части сказуемого](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6)

Также:

> Имя существительное в роли именной части употребляется обычно в формах именительного или творительного падежа. **Именительный** обозначает признак *постоянный*, *устойчивый*. При отнесенности к плану прошлого, такой именительный может восприниматься как архаичный. Признак *временный*, *непостоянный* передается чаще при помощи формы **творительного** падежа.

[Именная часть сказуемого](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-015.htm)

Т.е. в данном случае возможно такое противопоставление:

> (В то время) он был **вором** (но потом прекратил заниматься воровством).

или

> Он был **вор** *со стажем* (т.е. это являлось его основным занятием).

или даже оба падежа вместе:

> Он был **вор вором** (т.е. отъявленным вором).

Comment: Вот, кстати, хорошо, что про конструкцию именительный+творительный напомнили. Для тех, кто учит русский язык, это может быть очень интересно.

Answer (score 4):

*Был вором* = занимался воровством; *был вор* = являлся вором по своей сути.

Это примерно как в английском *What he was* vs *Who he was*.

Comment: Interesting explanation! It makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you have here is the **complex predicate** consisting of the helping verb "be" ("есть" : "был" 3rd person Past Tense) *and the noun phrase*.  That is similar to the sentence:

> Я - пользователь на сайте StackExchange.

In that sentence '**я**' - subject and '**пользователь**' - predicate.  The verb 'есть' is omitted and replaced with a dash.  With the verb omitted the noun has nominative case.  With the verb, like in your sentence, it can be in Instrumental case or in Nominative case.  See more [here](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_1_5).